# M Language (Power Query) Salesforce Web API - Passing Collections?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to query a Salesforce Datasource using the Salesforce API in Power BI.

The issue I am having is that the Salesforce API requires the SOQL to either contain a WHERE clause on the specific query being performed, by using an explicit value "=" or a IN operator.

If I use something like the following

```
each ([Column] = "value")
```

It works, however if I try and pass a list like the following:

```
each List.Contains(myList, [Column])
```

It fails with an error because the SOQL query being executed in the background clearly does a filtering AFTER all the data has been returned (i.e being filtered in Power BI after its been retrieved and not at source) and the Web API is expecting a IN operating with a list of values.

With regards to the first query, this works because the SOQL in the background is WHERE (MyField = 'someValue')

Does anyone have any ways around this? Can Power BI pass a collection into a where clause some way?

If not, I thought about querying the records by a single value and looping through this but it will have performance issues and not the best way of doing such query!

I have also tried joining the tables on the field I need but it also looks like the joins are performed after the data is retrived and not before (using SOQL).

I cannot modify the Web API to support other queries.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have anything else in your query that might break query folding? When I tried the `List.Contains()`, it interpreted it using an `IN` operation in the Native Query (SQL) view.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, are you trying this with the salesforce api or sql datasource as it may be a different result. Interesting to hear that though. I will do some further testing with List.Contains thanks. Any suggestions on how I am using it?